# Creating a right sided Pyramid with alternating rows

Tags: java

So for an assignment I was tasked with creating a pattern using loops that out puts something like this

```
            a
          B A
        c b a
      D C B A
    e d c b a
  F E D C B A
g f e d c b a
```

where the the input n is = to the number of rows printed.

so far I know I have to print the spaces first and then print the values

I have the code for the spaces so far the asterisks are just so I can see if I had the right amount of spaces.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW0407 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = input.nextInt();
        //int x = 7;


System.out.println("Pattern C");
        int a = 0;
        int b = x - 2;
        String s1 = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
        String s2 = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";

        for (int row = 0; row < x; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col <= b; col++) {

                System.out.print(" " + "*");

                if (col == b) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            b = b - 1;

        }
```

The string values are there because I had an Idea to make it so where I had an if statement like so

```
if(row % 2 == 0){

string str = s2.substring(25 - row, 25);

}

else{

string str = s1.substring(25 - row, 25);

}
```

I want to figure out where to start, should I make a new loop, a nested loop within the first for loop or place it in the already created nested loop.

I'm sorry if I make some weird mistakes, I'm still fairly confused on loops since I was just introduced to it. I had suggestions to use arrays and multiple methods but I am not allowed to use those since they were not covered subjects yet.

Comment: It looks like you currently have it printing upside down. You're right that you will need to print a the spaces first. Think of it this way, in your example, the top row has 6 spaces and 1 character. The next row has 5 spaces and 2 characters, the next 4 spaces and 3 characters. Use your loop to adjust the number of spaces and characters you need to print as you do each row.

Answer (score 2):

You only need 2 loops that iterate through the rows and columns (which you have).

As you iterate through the columns, use the following logic:

1. If column index >= column index - row index, print the character at 25-total # of columns + column index
2. If column index < column index - row index, print a space.

You seem to have figured out how to tell whether you should be printing capital or lowercase letters, so you should have all you need to write up the full solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help, though I do have a question. So far for placing the alternating capitalized lines I just place it, and proceed with trial and error. Is there a way to figure out a sense of where to have it out put in which loop by looking at the code? I see all these nested loops and can't understand how placing it in the inner vs outer loop works.

Comment: So far from what I read I know I must use an if statement to get it to print spaces then characters, but in order to print the substring I would need to create another if statement to alternate. My problem is that I don't really know where or how to determine where to place my if statement.

Comment: You place the if statements inside the nested loop that iterates through the columns.  The if statement that determines whether you print caps or lower case should be nested inside case one from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
    int x = 6;
    String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char output = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

        for(int j = x; j > 0; j--) {

            if(j > i + 1) { 
                output = ' ';
            } else  { 
                output = letters.charAt((j - 1) % letters.length()); 
            }

            if (i % 2 == 1) output = Character.toUpperCase(output);
            System.out.print(" " + output + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

and output:

```
               a 
            B  A 
         c  b  a 
      D  C  B  A 
   e  d  c  b  a 
F  E  D  C  B  A
```